# Autofac WCF integration + sessions

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, session, autofac

I am having an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that collaborates with a WCF service, which is hosted using Autofac host factory. Here are some code samples:

.svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
Language="C#" 
Debug="true"
Service="MyNamespace.IMyContract, MyAssembly" 
Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf" %>
```

Global.asax of the WCF service project:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();        

    //Here I perform all registrations, including implementation of IMyContract

    AutofacServiceHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();            
}
```

Client proxy class constructor (MVC side):

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register(c => new ChannelFactory<IMyContract>(
    new BasicHttpBinding(),
    new EndpointAddress(Settings.Default.Url_MyService)))
    .SingleInstance();

builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ChannelFactory<IMyContract>>().CreateChannel())
    .UseWcfSafeRelease();

_container = builder.Build();
```

This works fine until I want WCF service to allow or require sessions (`[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]`, or `[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]`) and to share one session with the MVC side. I changed the binding to WSHttpBinding on the MVC side, but I am having different exceptions depending on how I tune it.

I also tried changing `AutofacServiceHostFactory` to `AutofacWebServiceHostFactory`, with no result.

I am not using config file as I am mainly experimenting, not developing real-life application, but I need to study the case. But if you think I can achieve what I need only with config files, then OK, I'll use them.

I will provide exception details for each combination of settings if required, I'm omitting them not to make the post too large. Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: You should post the exceptions that you are getting as well. That might help throw some light on the problem

Comment: More than a year passed since then :) I do not even remember what I was trying to do.

Comment: I'd appreciat if someone could tell me how to close / delete this question without need to wait for others' votes.